# How do I see in my controller what radiobuttons have been checked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I am sorry if I ask a newbie question but i am new to asp.net mvc.

So, I have this view :

```
@model FirstProject.Models.SelectRolesViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SelectRolesOverall","SelectRoles"))
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Users</th>
            <th>Roles</th>
        </tr>
        @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.UsersAndRoles)
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

And the EditorTemplate :

```
@model FirstProject.Models.UserRole

    <tr>
        <td>@Model.User.UserName</td>
        <td>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Role, "Applicant") Applicant
            <br/>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Role, "Professor") Professor
        </td>
    </tr>
```

My question is next : How do I see what radio buttons have been checked in my controller after the submit button has been pressed? I want to have the following logic : If Applicant have been selected then userRole is Applicant , else if Professor has been selected then userrole is Professor. My controller is Empty momentarily because I don't know what to write in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your action method is

```
public SelectRolesOverall(SelectRolesViewModel model)
```

then you can access the collection with

```
IEnumerable<UsersAndRoles> usesAndRoles = model.UsersAndRoles;
```

and access each item in the collection

```
foreach (UserRole userRole in model.UsersAndRoles)
{
  string role = userRole.Role;
  string name = userRole.UserName; // see note below
}
```

Note you have not included an input for the property `UserName` so this value wont post back and you might have trouble matching the role to the user. You might want to add `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserName)` or change `<td>@Model.User.UserName</td>` to `<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public ActionResult [YourActionName](string role)
{
   switch(role){
      case "Applicant": /*your applicant logic*/
          break;
      case "Professor": /*your Professor logic*/
          break;
      /*
          Other logic here
      */
}
```

Replace the action name by your own
**Note** that the parameter `role` should have the same name of the radio button in your view, this is to allow data binding to work